# Why doesn't my simple routine to avoid generating two random numbers in a row work?

Tags: javascript, random

I'm doing the random quote generator Free Code Camp challenge, but don't want to have the same quote twice in a row. I came to the exact same conclusion as the person here did: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62018/prevent-repetitive-random-numbers

However, he says his works but mine still does not. My pen can be found here: http://codepen.io/thomasdean/pen/qZGQxK

And the code is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#getQuote").on("click", function() {
      $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/thomasdean/pen/Yqmgyx.js", function(json) {

        var html = "";
        var lastQuote = "";
        var whichQuoteToChoose = "";

        while (whichQuoteToChoose === lastQuote) {
          whichQuoteToChoose = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12); // returns a number between 0 and 11
        }
        lastQuote = whichQuoteToChoose;

        // this converts raw data into html

        json = json.filter(function(val) {
          return (val.id == whichQuoteToChoose);
        });

        json.forEach(function(val) {

          html += "<div class = 'quote'>"

          html += "<h2>\"" + val.Quotation + "\"</h2><h2>" + val.Quotee + "</h2>"

          html += "</div>"

        });

        $(".quote").html(html);

      });
    });
  });
```

With the while loop and the assignment immediately after it being what should, in theory, solve the problem.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Show us a sample of what the JSON data looks like

Comment: It's here: http://codepen.io/thomasdean/pen/Yqmgyx.js

Comment: does the data ever change between button clicks?

Comment: You reset `lastQuote` to an empty string every time the button is clicked.

Comment: theaccordance: yes, it does

Comment: Juhana: you've nailed it, thanks. So... how do I stop that? In codepen it seems the javascript has to be separate from the html

Comment: Let me rephrase, does the json data being returned from the json call ever change

Comment: theaccordance: If I understand you right, yes. When you click the button, the getJSON returns a different quote, thanks to the filter. It just does it twice in a row sometimes (once, it did it four times in a row)

Comment: Also, not really sure why you have to do the AJAX call again every time. Couldn't you run it once at page load and save the results?

Comment: Juhana: I'm just using the routines that Free Code Camp gave me. Arturas  showed me below how to stop lastquote getting reset every time. I thought I'd have to take it out of the entire javascript somehow, and was confused. Glad there's an easy solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Just dont rewrite lastQuote and whichQuoteToChoose on each click event. so i moved those variables out of click event :)

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     var lastQuote = "";
    var whichQuoteToChoose = "";
     $("#getQuote").on("click", function() {
         $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/thomasdean/pen/Yqmgyx.js", function(json) {

        var html = "";


        //alert(lastQuote)
        while (whichQuoteToChoose === lastQuote) {
          whichQuoteToChoose = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12); // returns a number between 0 and 11
        }
        lastQuote = whichQuoteToChoose;

        // this converts raw data into html

        json = json.filter(function(val) {
          return (val.id == whichQuoteToChoose);
        });

        json.forEach(function(val) {

          html += "<div class = 'quote'>"

          html += "<h2>\"" + val.Quotation + "\"</h2><h2>" + val.Quotee + "</h2>"

          html += "</div>"

        });

        $(".quote").html(html);

      });
    });
  });
```